# Concatenate two strings into one without duplicates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two strings:

```
DECLARE @str1 varchar(max) = '[First Name],[Last Name],[Middle Name]'
DECLARE @str2 varchar(max) = '[First Name],[Pin Code],[Address],[Last Name]'
```

Want to concatenate two strings into one without duplicates.

Expected Output:

```
str3
-------------------------------------------------------------
[First Name],[Last Name],[Middle Name],[Pin Code],[Address]
```

Comment: You need a string split function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`STRING_SPLIT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function and `DISTINCT` as

```
DECLARE @str1 varchar(max) = '[First Name],[Last Name],[Middle Name]';
DECLARE @str2 varchar(max) = '[First Name],[Pin Code],[Address],[Last Name]';

SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Str1 +','+ @Str2, ',');
```

Or

```
DECLARE @str1 varchar(max) = '[First Name],[Last Name],[Middle Name]';
DECLARE @str2 varchar(max) = '[First Name],[Pin Code],[Address],[Last Name]';

SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM STRING_SPLIT(CONCAT(@Str1, ',', @Str2), ',');
```

to get it as one row

```
declare @result varchar(max) = '';

SELECT @result =  @result + value
FROM STRING_SPLIT(CONCAT(@Str1, ',', @Str2), ',')
group by value;

SELECT @result;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9fdb459b846fcab09994cf1518f14126)**

and since you are working on SQL Server 2008 you need to create your own function such [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10914602/6426692).

Comment: I think need to put `+','+` between `@str1` and `@str2` in the split function.

Comment: @Squirrel Really? why + and not ,?? does this run?

Comment: my mistake. Need coffee